# KDE application launcher shortcut is erased by reboot

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde

I would like to use Ctrl+Esc to bring up the application launcher.  I can define that shortcut and it works until I reboot, but then it is erased.  I am running KDE 18.04.  There is a related discussion under "Keyboard shortcuts not working after upgrading to Kubuntu 18.04".  I have the libkf5globalaccel-* stuff already installed.  How do I add kglobalaccel5 to autostart?